# How do I use Date::Manip to create a date usable by Date::ICal?

Tags: perl, datetime

I need to take the result of a `Date::Manip ParseDateString()` and use it as the bast for an `Date::ICal::Event`

`Date::ICal::Event` has the following date creating inputs:

```
use Date::ICal;

$ical = Date::ICal->new( ical => '19971024T120000' );
$ical = Date::ICal->new( epoch => time );
$ical = Date::ICal->new( year => 1964,
    month => 10, day => 16, hour => 16,
    min => 12, sec => 47 );
```

`Date::Manip ParseDateString()` returns a standard date value.

How should I use that date in the ICal date?  Convert to epoch? Can it easily be converted to the ical format?  I feel like this should be easier than it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some further CPAN hunting and came up with the module `DateTime::Format::DateManip`

Using this I was able to convert it to a DateTime representation and then get the epoch from that using the epoch method available in DateTime:

```
my $cagedate = ParseDateString($cagewatch);
my $cagedatetime = DateTime::Format::DateManip->parse_datetime($cagedate);

$vevent->add_properties(
    summary => $cagemovie,
    description => $cagemovie,
    dtstart   => Date::ICal->new( epoch => $cagedatetime->epoch )->ical,
);
```

Just in case you are curious about the CAGE variables.  I was parsing the list of movies for the [Year of the Cage](http://www.screened.com/news/screened-presents-year-of-the-cage/3258/%20%22Year%20of%20the%20Cage%27).  All Nick Cage, all year.  Oh yeah.

Comment: That'll work, but introducing another large date module just to do the conversion is hardly the easiest (or quickest) method.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that, if you've got a date *into* Date::Manip successfully, you can just use its [printf directives](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-6.53/lib/Date/Manip/Date.pod#PRINTF_DIRECTIVES) to output it in any format you want.

It looks like `%Y%m%dT%H%M%S` is what you want for iCal.

Comment: You need `%Y` instead of `%y` (or just `%Q`, which means `%Y%m%d`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd do:

```
sub date2ical
{
  my $date = shift;

  Date::ICal->new( ical   => UnixDate($date, '%QT%H%M%S'), # %Q means %Y%m%d
                   offset => UnixDate($date, '%z'));
} # end date2ical

# Usage:
my $ical = date2ical(ParseDateString('today'));
```

This should properly handle timezones (provided Date::Manip gets the timezone right).

Answer (score 1):

Your life will be so much easier if you dump Date::Manip and switch to [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime) for all your date and time processing. There's even a [DateTime::Format::ICal](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aICal) to help with this specific task.